# Google analytics - event hits don't work after sendHitTask

Tags: google-analytics

Just started integration of Salesforce Community with Universal Google Analytics (beginner in both).
Adding GA integration code in  tag.
Downloaded GA debugger for Chrome.
Browser: Chrome.
Here is code in the  tag:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
  {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||
  []).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date 
  ();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
  [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})
  (window,document,'script','https://www.google-
  analytics.com/analytics_debug.js','ga');

  window.ga_debug = {trace: true};
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');            
    
  ga('send', 'pageview');    

  ga(function(tracker) { 
      
      tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {  

          var hitPayload = model.get ( 'hitPayload' ); 

          console.log ( 'models payload: ' + hitPayload );

          // need this section to get user id value to send to dimension
          //ga('set', 'dimension3', tracker.get('userId'));                         
     });
   });     

</script>
```

Later in the code we make calls to track events.
After I've added
"ga(function(tracker) {"  code section
those calls to track events do Not work any more (used to work).

What is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `sendHitTask` for the tracker, you're overriding it; that is, you're removing the normal task that sends data to Google Analytics and replacing it with your own. So, after you do this, any hits you track won't be sent to GA.

Instead, before you set the `sendHitTask`, you need to get the existing one and execute that function first in your new `sendHitTask` function.

From [documentation for adding to a task](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks), some code to do this follows. Before your `tracker.set` call, you need to add:

```
// Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');
```

Then, in your function that you're assigning to `sendHitTask`, you'll need to call that function:

```
// Send the normal request to Google Analytics
originalSendHitTask(model);
```

Comment: This answer is correct to resolve "events not been sent" issue. But please also see next answer by Eike, that did help me to get userId correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You have crippled your sendHitTask, because the method you provided to override it does not do any sending - you have replaced it with a function that logs something to the console and nothing else.

If you look at the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#overriding_a_task) you see that there they stored the original sendHitTask in a variable and called within the custom function.

Also you cannot use the ga object within the task, you access the properties of your tracker via the model that is passed in to the task.

So you would need something like

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  // Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
  var originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');

  tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
     model.set('dimension3',model.get('userId'));
     originalSendHitTask(model);  
  });
});
```

Also you might consider to use the customTask to add custom behavior, although it will give the same result.

Comment: Many thanks, Prev answer is correct to resolve "events not been sent" issue. But Many thanks for your answer also, it did help me to get userId correctly. I've voted for both.